# How to get a specific video's ad status via YouTube (Partner) API?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to get a videos ad status, to detect if the video ad status changed to limited or no ads. This [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) on video list does not return the ad status. This [partner api request](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtubePartner/v1/youtubePartner.videoAdvertisingOptions.get) does not give the status of ads and [its cousin api](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtubePartner/v1/youtubePartner.videoAdvertisingOptions.getEnabledAds) does not give the status of ads for a video.

Thus how does one tell if monetization has been turned off or the state is restricted due to **LIMITED_OR_NO_ADS**